# MongoClient class not found with MAMP

Tags: php, mongodb, mamp

- I have downloaded and installed MongoDB.
- I can interact with my db via the `mongo` shell.
- I have installed the PHP extension through `sudo pecl install mongo`
- I confirmed that `mongo.so` is in the folder defined by `extension_dir` in php.ini.
- I have confirmed that `extension=mongo.so` is defined in php.ini.
- I confirmed that the php.ini file I edited is the php.ini file being loaded for configuration via `phpinfo()`.

Yet when I try to instantiate a new MongoClient, my script fails silently.  And I when I try to run a command like `php --rc MongoClient`, I receive an error that the class does not exist.  I have restarted apache (MAMP) and the computer and reverified config files multiple times.  As I can use mongodb and mongo, I assume this is a PHP configuration issue, but I've double checked config multiple times. Any ideas?

Edit: php_error.log output:

> [20-Aug-2014 18:54:03 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MongoClient' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pantry/application/controllers/mongodb.php on line 14
>
> [20-Aug-2014 18:54:56 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mongo: Unable to initialize module
>
> Module compiled with module API=20100525
>
> PHP    compiled with module API=20121212
>
> These options need to match
>    in Unknown on line 0

The issue now is clear, but I do not how to resolve it.

Comment: Turn up `error_reporting`, you may be suppressing errors generated at startup. Depending on your settings the errors may also be going to syslog or Apache logs.

Comment: I dumped the logs in an edit. It is clear now the problem, but I do not how to fix. @Sammitch

Answer (score 0):

Alright - so the final solution was hinted at around other similar questions. I had everything in the right place, using the right PHP, mongo, etc, but phpize was still configured with the wrong api version.  So I downloaded the latest version of the applicable PHP source code, stuffed it all in /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/include/php, reran pecl, restarted apache, and am good to go.